# Creating a thread

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I know I can create a thread within a program with `CreateThread()` and I need to `WaitForSingleObject()` for it to finish before returning to the original program.

My question is, is the original program a thread as well? 
Say, I have a variable `a=3` in my program, then I create a thread. From the second thread, can I get access to my variable `a`?

Comment: Uh ... generally speaking the point of creating additional threads is so that your program can be doing several things at once, so creating a thread and then immediately calling `WaitForSingleObject` is pretty much pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Windows O/S starts a process it will also create the first thread for that process.

So, the "original program" is the wrong name. But the initial item the is executing the progra m is a thread.

When your variable scope allows the access from the second thread than you can access it. If you want to pass access to a specific variable you can use the appropriate parameter to `CreateThread` to pass a pointer to it. But beware: When the execution of the original thread goes out of the scope of this variable then the pointer gets invalid. I recommend to consider a redesign.

*Edit*
As requested, here is a example for variable going a out of scope.
This would be a wrong implementation:

```
DWORD TheThread(void*p)
{
    int *pcounter = (int*)p;
    // do anything with pcounter
}

HANDLE MakeItRun()
{
    int counter;
    return CreateThread(0, 0, &TheThread, &counter, 0, 0);
} // scope of counter ends here

int main()
{
    HANDLE h;
    h = MakeItRun();
    WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE);
}
```

Comment: So if it's in a superior code block, my thread will find it? It doesn't have to be global? Also, Is the thread unique for the full duration of the original program?

Comment: Each thread has it's own stack for the runtime of the thread. This includes all local variables until the scope of the variable is left.

Comment: Can you show me an example where the variable is out of scope? I can't imagine it going out of scope when the thread is created after the variable is. It can be pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work:

```
DWORD WINAPI threadProc(LPVOID param)
{
    a = 5;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadProc, NULL, 0, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);
}
```

The compiler will issue an error telling you that `a` is undeclared in `threadProc`.

You can pass a pointer though:

```
DWORD WINAPI threadProc(LPVOID param)
{
    int *aPtr = (int *)param;
    *aPtr = 5;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadProc, &a, 0, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);
    // value of a is now 5
}
```

This is a perfectly correct technique, as long as you ensure that the scope of the stack variable outlives the thread.

You can also share memory between threads with global variables or their alternate forms (singleton classes, static class variables).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - a thread is the OS fundamental unit of execution.  No threadee, no runnee.